# PostgreSQL Auto Increment Insert Into with PHP 7 Issue

Tags: php, postgresql, increment

I've only recently started to learn about databases in college late last year and have been trying to learn a bit more in my own time.
I was advised to try PostgreSQL last Week and have hit a brick wall with trying to auto increment the account ID to a database.

The system is meant to automatically add the new unique ID to the account table in row "a_pid" while adding in the form POST email, username and password.

**Current error message**

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "email" does not
>   exist LINE 1: ...NTO account (a_pid, email, username, pwd) VALUES
>   (email-3@ex... ^ HINT: There is a column named "email" in table
>   "account", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

**DDL**

```
create table account (
    a_pid serial primary key,
    email varchar (64),
    username varchar (16),
    pwd varchar (32)
);
```

**DDL Insert Data**

```
Insert into account (a_pid,email,username,pwd) values (0,'email-0@example.com','Zero','12345678');
Insert into account (a_pid,email,username,pwd) values (1,'email-1@example.com','One','password123'); 
Insert into account (a_pid,email,username,pwd) values (2,'email-2@example.com','Two','53cureP@s5w0rd');
```

**Form "index.php"**

```
<form name="signup" action="sign-up.php" method="post">
    Email <input name="email" type="text" maxlength="64" value="Please enter your email" onfocus="(this.value == 'Please enter your email') && (this.value = '')"   onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = 'Please enter your email')"><br/>
    Verify Email <input name="vf_email" type="text" maxlength="64" value="Please enter your email" onfocus="(this.value == 'Please enter your email') && (this.value = '')" onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = 'Please enter your email')"><br/>
    Username: <input name="username" type="text" maxlength="16" value="username" onfocus="(this.value == 'username) && (this.value = '')"   onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = 'username')"><br/>
    Password: <input name="pwd" type="password" minlength="8" maxlength="32"><br/>
    Password: <input name="vf_pwd" type="password" minlength="8" maxlength="32"><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
</form>
```

**PHP Insert "sign-up.php"**

```
<?php 
$conn = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=sql_account user=postgres password=databaseconnect";
$dbconn = pg_connect($conn);

$email = pg_escape_string($_POST['email']); 
$username = pg_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$pwd = pg_escape_string($_POST['pwd']); 

$query = "INSERT INTO account (a_pid, email, username, pwd) VALUES (". $email .", ". $username .", ". $pwd .");
SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('account','a_pid'))";

$result = pg_query($query); 
?>
```

Comment: Check the message, it says something is wrong near the ")", and in  `Three, 123,);` you can see that you have one extra comma after "123" but there is no new value. Delete that and try again

Comment: (1) I believe postgresql requires string literals to be quoted, ie `'email-0@example.com'`, but you are missing them in your code -> `VALUES (". $email .",...` should be `VALUES ('". $email ."',...`. (2) you specify `a_pid` in your columns `(a_pid, email, username, pwd)` but not in your values. Either remove it, or add a `null` before your email -> `VALUES (null, '". $email ."',...`. (3) as was mentioned, remove the last `,`. (4) I doubt `pg_query()` allows multi queries, so you will need to remove the `SELECT ...`

Comment: @Acapulco removed 1 error got another...
Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "email" does not exist LINE 1: ...NTO account (a_pid, email, username, pwd) VALUES (email-3@ex... ^ HINT: There is a column named "email" in table "account", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: @Sean
Thank you for the advise, will give it a go tomorrow night and post any progression. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message you're getting — this isn't anything to do with your auto-incremented sequence ids. As @titan-studios says, the `email` field appears to be missing in your DB structure.

That aside, you're not specifying an actual value for your `a_pid` field in the `VALUES` part of your SQL — you specify `a_pid, email, username, pwd` fields but only give `$email, $username, $pwd` values.

Why not let Postgres do the work for you and don't specify the id field at all? Defining a field as `serial` will set a default value of the next value of the sequence automatically.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Additionally, I'd **strongly** suggest looking at parameterised prepared queries instead of string concatenation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php

```
$query = "INSERT INTO account (email, username, pwd) VALUES ($1, $2, $3);
```